# HP iLO: How to fix "Monitor is in graphics mode or an unsupported text mode."?

Tags: hp-proliant

When I use the iLO functionality of my HP server that allows me to SSH into the iLO IP address and run `TEXTCONS` to display the monitor output as a text.

However, on boot, after a few initial kernel/startup messages, switches to only showing:

```
Monitor is in graphics mode or an unsupported text mode.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: By the way, when `Monitor is in graphics mode or an unsupported text mode.` is shown, usually inputs (e.g. pressing keys) still works, even though you cannot see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

**For Linux:**

Add the `vga=normal nomodeset` kernel boot parameters.

You can add them via your bootloader (e.g. GRUB2) configuration to persist them, or in e.g. GRUB2 press `e` on the menu entry and add them at the end of the `linux` line to apply them to a single boot.

**For GRUB2:**

Use the `/etc/default/grub` setting `GRUB_TERMINAL="console"` ([see manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html)).

This prevents GRUB2 to go into graphical VGA mode (the one that allows it to e.g. display a logo at the top), and forces it to display its menu in the classical console fashion instead.

If you do not use `/etc/default/grub` but use GRUB2 *commands* instead (e.g. if you generate `grub.cfg` itself, like [NixOS](https://nixos.org/nixos/) does), you can use the commands that `GRUB_TERMINAL` generates for you directly:

```
terminal_output console
terminal_input console
```

(Side note: You can also enable the serial console and afterwards use `GRUB_TERMINAL="console serial"` to make it work in the iLO's `VSP` mode in addition; for more on that, see my [VSP answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/830748/how-to-enable-and-use-the-serial-terminal-of-a-hp-microserver-gen9/830749#830749).)

### Explanation

`TEXTCONS` only supports a standard VGA terminal.

Details:

- [`vga=normal`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/svga.txt) because TEXTCONS does apparently not support extended VGA modes (which allow more than `80x25` characters).

  GRUB2 will print something about `vga=normal` being deprecated, but that
  is just its own opinion, Linux did not deprecate the boot option.
- `nomodeset` to prevent the kernel to do the "kernel mode switch" that gives modern computers pretty higher-resolution virtual terminals.

This is also explained at https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c02700808&docLocale=en_US. I don't know what the `3` in `nomodeset 3` shown there at the end of the kernel parameters means, but it seems it is unnecessary.

Comment: My related [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1175602/how-to-enable-and-use-the-serial-terminal-of-a-hp-microserver-gen9) about using `VSP`.

Comment: Sorry, better link: That [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/830748/how-to-enable-and-use-the-serial-terminal-of-a-hp-microserver-gen9/830749#830749) was apparently copied to ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

### Tedted on Ubuntu 20.04

Forget about TEXTCONS and use the **VSP** command instead. It works just fine.

Change/append this line to your `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty0 console=ttyS1,115200n8"
```

Reboot the system

- `tty0` will be the console you can use trough the web UI
- `ttyS1` will be the console you can use with VSP - after connected to the ilo via ssh

###### **On RHEL based systems if VSP would not work, try `ttyS0` instead**!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: VSP also works, but this question was specifically about `TEXTCONS`. I posted a related question + answer about `VSP` as written in this comment on the question: https://superuser.com/questions/1541093/hp-ilo-how-to-fix-monitor-is-in-graphics-mode-or-an-unsupported-text-mode/1687989#comment2347372_1541094 That agrees with your findings.